# Demonstration using Spock

Tags: spock

I'm going to be doing a presentation on Spock next week and as part of the presentation I need to give a demonstration.  I have used Spock a bit before for a project but haven't used it in about a year or so.

The demonstration needs to be more than just a "hello world" type demonstration.  I'm looking for ideas of cool things I can demonstrate using Spock ... Any ideas?

The only thing I have now is the basic example that is included in the "getting started" section of the Spock website.

```
def "length of Spock's and his friends' names"() {
    expect:
    name.size() == length

    where:
    name << ["Kirk", "Spock", "Scotty"]
    length << [4,5,6]
    /*
    name     | length
    "Spock"  | 5
    "Kirk"   | 4
    "Scotty" | 6
    */
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same tool for end-to-end testing as well as unit testing. Since it is based on groovy you can provide your own simple domain specific dsl based automation framework leveraging spock. I've around 5000 automated tests running as part of CI using this framework.

For Acceptance Testing

1. use of power asserts focus on how easy it is to interpret the failed assertions
2. BDD with given-when-then
3. data driven specs and unrolling
4. business friendly reporting
5. Powerful UI automation by marrying with [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/)

For unit and integration testing

1. interaction based testing and mocking
2. simplified xml etc testing because of groovy goodies

Get more ideas from their [documentation](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/)

Comment: Thank you for the response - I really appreciate it.  Also, somewhat unrelated, I also need to talk about the architecture of Spock and discuss some of the and design patterns used within it.  I've been searching the web for a while and haven't found any good resources.  Are there any components/design patterns that I can talk about?  Thanks again.

Comment: @joshft91 Did I answer your question? Do you have any follow up questions?

Comment: I'm sold on Spock's cool Groovy syntax. But the setup with maven and it Gradle is totally intimidating. If I was giving a demo, I'd focus on easiest way to get started.